# CloudWatch agent error log - metrics are not showing up in console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, agent, ssm

I installed the cloudwatch agent in EC2 instance with proper roles attached to it.
As i see in command line,the cloudwatch agent was running and but i don't see metrics being collected and showed up in GUI.
I checked the log file.This is how it is 
[image]

May I know what this actually means and how to resolve it.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: How did you setup the client? Maybe you set it up in a way you would setup an on-premise server?

Comment: not like a on premise one